# android get screen width from an appwidget

Tags: android, widget

how can i do that? is there a way to do it without a context: (getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth())

Answer (score 1):

App widgets have access to a `Context` -- it is passed into the `AppWidgetProvider`.